# Counter-example to show that this system is non-linear?

Tags: discrete-signals, non-linear

I have a discrete-time system `y[n] = x[n]*x[n-1]`

I need to show that this system is non-linear by using a counter example rather than by disproving with algebra and the properties of additivity and homogeneity.

I think that the system is homogeneous although not additive, but I can't think of an example to show this. Would someone help me out please?

Comment: Hint: try with constant signals.

Comment: It's not even homogeneous. Really, nearly any two signals will work as a counter example. There's nothing complicated about constructing a counter example. Just take something and plug it in.

Comment: Hmm when I tried to do the algebra to see if it was homogeneous I got `a*x[n] -> a*y[n]`, I guess I screwed up somewhere. I'm really just not familiar with how this works. Say I take a unit impulse and put it in, then I get a signal of 0 out. Then I shift the unit impulse to the right and put it in and still get a signal of 0 out. I wish I had an example to get me started.

Comment: You are testing shift invariance with your example, not linearity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Let's try homogeneity again:
$$
y[n] = x[n]\cdot x[n-1]
$$
for input $x[n]$.

For input $a\cdot x[n]$ we get
$$
y'[n] = a\cdot x[n] \cdot a x[n-1] = a^2 \cdot x[n]\cdot x[n-1] \not = ay[n]
$$
so homogeneity doesn't apply.

Let's try that with an example, as per MBaz's suggestion.

Let's try:
$$
x[n] = 2
$$
so that
$$
y[n] = 4
$$
Then let's try twice that:
$$
x'[n] = 2\cdot x[n] = 4
$$
So that
$$
y'[n] = 16 \not= 2\cdot y[n]
$$

Comment: Ah, I added instead of multiplying. Thank you I'm starting to get the examples now